# No such file or directory while executing a shell file in google colab

Tags: bash, google-colaboratory

I am running a machine translation code in google colab for that I cloned the code into my drive and stored the drive location in a variable:

```
!PATH='/content/mydrive/My Drive/facebook/unsup'
```

The cloning was succesfully done in the desired location.
The problem arises when I try to run a shell file:

```
!."$PATH/NMT/get_data_enfr.sh"
```

it returns

```
/bin/bash: ./content/mydrive/My Drive/facebook/unsup/NMT/get_data_enfr.sh: No such file or directory
```

But if I run

```
!head "$PATH/NMT/get_data_enfr.sh"
```

It shows the file content.

```
# Copyright (c) 2018-present, Facebook, Inc.
# All rights reserved.
#
# This source code is licensed under the license found in the
# LICENSE file in the root directory of this source tree.
#

set -e

#
```

Comment: Why do you have a `!` symbol at the start of every command you run? Does it mean that the command is run from the terminal?

Comment: In Ipython '!' is specified before every bash command to differentiate it from the python command.

Comment: May be the first '.' in the '!."$PATH/NMT/get_data_enfr.sh"' is causing bash to search for the file under the current folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try running the script as :

```
sh "$PATH/NMT/get_data_enfr.sh"
```

Before running it like above, please run the below command :

```
chmod +x "$PATH/NMT/get_data_enfr.sh"
```

It seems @dash-o is correct, When you are running the script using `.` in front of script, it actually looking for script from the current directory.

It's working for `head` command because there the complete path is being passed to `head` and it is finding the file at that path but not true while running it.

`./path/to/script` actually trying to run the script from the current directory and ignoring the absolute path. But when using `sh` and then `$PATH`, it actually running from the absolute path.

Comment: Yes, the **.** was the problem, it was treating the shell file from the current directory. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

You have to escape the space with a single backslash.
Example: `PATH=/omg/a\ space`
Also its a good idea to put the output in " or ' with `echo \"${PATH}\"`

Comment: But the ls, cat and head commands work perfectly. I even tried it locally, at first I thought it was due the execution permission of the file. But if I run it from the same directory there is no problem. Whereas if I run the executable shell via a variable stored path, it is not working.

Comment: Yes, you right. I extended the above example. I can test at the moment only on a unrooted android device with connectbot.